# Panel with 1 child should fill but more children and panel should scrunch them in

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I'm not sure that title gets the point across. I'm making a Day view for a calendar with timeslots on the left and then any appointment pointing to that timeslot in a panel on the right. If there is one appointment, it should fill the entire horizontal space but, if there are more (conflicting appointment times), they should resize to fit in the one line, side-by-side and still fill all horizontal space. Basically, exactly how Outlook does it on their day view.

So, I've tried a multitude of setups with different combos of stackpanels, itempanels, uniformgrids, etc. DockPanel seems to be the one I want as its child fills the space, but further appointments in the same slot and I get vertical lines added (I want them to "scrunch" horizontally). I feel like stretching stackpanel and its children isn't the proper way to do this, but I can't figure out how I should do it.

Here is what I have thus far (I've removed unimportant stuff like styling and binding names to make it less daunting, rest assured, all the data is there):

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TimeBlocks}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Time}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Appts}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <customs:ApptPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: UniformGrid with one row should do it.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I knew there had to be something I wasn't thinking of.